# How to set up NERDTree to CD to current folder when opening it for the first time via :NERDTreeFind

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, working-directory

Given:

```
$ cd ~/Sites/project
project $ vim
:NERDTreeFind
```

I would like to see NERDTree opening with `~/Sites/project` as a root folder.

Instead I see `~/Sites` with `project` folder selected. So I have to `cd` to the work folder each time.

I am sure there should be a setting for that but I can't find it. Help.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:set autochdir` command to change the current directory. It will set the working directory as specific to the opened file.

Comment: This is the answer OP asked for!

Answer (score 3):

From the documention it would seem that it should be using your `~/Sites/project` directory. (See `:h :NERDTree`)

```
:NERDTree [<start-directory> | <bookmark>]                         *:NERDTree*
    Opens a fresh NERD tree. The root of the tree depends on the argument
    given. There are 3 cases: If no argument is given, the current directory
    will be used.  If a directory is given, that will be used. If a bookmark
    name is given, the corresponding directory will be used.  For example: >
        :NERDTree /home/marty/vim7/src
        :NERDTree foo   (foo is the name of a bookmark)

:NERDTreeToggle [<start-directory> | <bookmark>]             *:NERDTreeToggle*
    If a NERD tree already exists for this tab, it is reopened and rendered
    again.  If no NERD tree exists for this tab then this command acts the
    same as the |:NERDTree| command.
```

If `:NERDTreeToggle` is loading the incorrect directory you need to try the following:

- Verify the shell's current working directory. `<c-z>` to suspend Vim and then do `pwd`. Use `fg` to bring back Vim.
- Make sure your current working directory is set correctly inside of Vim. Check via `:pwd`.
- Do you have some plugin/customization that would change your current working directory?
- Error still occurring? Create a ticket in [NERDTree's tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues). Make sure you use a minimal vimrc and no plugins other than NerdTree so that others can reproduce this bug.

Comment: After restarting vim with everything commented out in `.vimrc` except nerdtree... everything is back to normal. I don't have any explanation for this at the moment, but it fixed itself.

Comment: Sorry it is not consistent actually. I need to investigate it further.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did in the end. Thanks to [GitHub](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/480)

```
function! NERDTreeToggleInCurDir()
  " If NERDTree is open in the current buffer
  if (exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
    exe ":NERDTreeClose"
  else
    if (expand("%:t") != '')
      exe ":NERDTreeFind"
    else
      exe ":NERDTreeToggle"
    endif
  endif
endfunction

" nnoremap <leader>nf :NERDTreeFind<cr>
nnoremap <leader>nf :call NERDTreeToggleInCurDir()<cr>
```

Comment: The exec’s aren’t necessary; you can write an ex command directly.

Answer (score 1):

From the NERDTree docs, you should be able to add the following to your .vimrc

```
"Open NERDTree if no files specified
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
```

This will open the present working directory if you do not specify a file to be opened when you call `vim`

I hope that helps!

Comment: what does `!exists("s:std_in")` mean?

Comment: I would imagine it pairs with argc==0 to check that a plain invocation of `vim` has been called. Then it opens NERDTree

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I use this (in my .vimrc):
`autocmd vimenter * silent! lcd %:p:h`

It sets the pwd to be the current folder (or, the folder/file given when launching vim).